# DependencyViolation occurred when I delete subnet after terminate instance using aws-sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I control AWS environment using AWS-SDK PHP.
When I delete all test environment, the problem has been occurred.

I read the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#deletesubnet) and I already know `DependencyViolation` is occurred if I have running instances in target subnet.

So I terminated running instance first, and after that, I tried to delete subnet, but `DependencyViolation` error is occurred.

I tried these sequences using this code.

```php
<?php
$options = [
    /**
     * information about region, version ..
     */
];
$client = new Ec2Client($options);

$promise = $client->terminateInstancesAsync([
    'InstanceIds' => ['instance-id'],
])->then(function ($result) use ($client) {
    return $client->deleteSubnetAsync([
        'SubnetId' => 'subnet-id',
    ]);
});
```

I guess the reason of error is "instance is not terminated perfactly but delete subnet action is run".

But I have no idea what I have to do for delete subnet without `DependencyViolation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use `deleteSubnet` method after using `terminateInstnaces` method without any errors using [`Waiters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#waiters).

I used these code.

```php
$promise = $client->terminateInstancesAsync([
    'InstanceIds' => ['instance-id'],
])->then(function ($result) use ($client) {
    $client->waitUntil('InstanceTerminated', [
        'InstanceIds' => ['instance-id'],
    ]);
    return $client->deleteSubnetAsync([
        'SubnetId' => 'subnet-id',
    ]);
});
```